# How do I create 'www' domain alias automatically?

Tags: dns, apache2

I created CNAME record for new domain: `www    CNAME    @`, now, if I have many domains, shoud I always create a link 'www.example.com' to 'example.com' folder? My apache VHOST config is:

```
UseCanonicalName Off

VirtualDocumentRoot /home/colix/www/hosts/%0
VirtualScriptAlias /home/colix/www/hosts/%0/cgi-bin
```

Answer (score 0):

for this case I always use ServerAlias directive in the config (see [Apache Doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/vhosts/name-based.html)).

```
ServerName domain.tld
ServerAlias www.domain.tld
ServerAlias mx.domain.tld
```

Greetings,
M.

Comment: Notice that I gave dynamic virtual hosting here, so this doesn't work